# Extensions listed more than once in my VS Code v1.79+ profile

Tags: php, kubernetes, visual-studio-code, wsl-2

I'm using VS Code with PHP and added a number of extensions to help with my PHP development and deployment to my k3d cluster. Somehow I have multiple extensions listed twice (duplicated) in the Profiles View. Please advise on how to debug/fix:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue currently in the backlog: [Why the extensions of profile are duplicated? #185186](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/185186). I'm not aware of any workarounds to get rid of the issue at the moment. I think all that can be done is to wait and give a thumbs up to the issue ticket to hopefully increase its prioritization. You can also subscribe to the issue ticket to get notified about discussion and updates. Please avoid making comments like "+1" / "bump". But do consider copy and pasting in the contents of the `Help: About` command (as text) as a comment there, which may help the maintainers get a better understanding of what the cause is.